# Hide a part of the screen when scrolling down

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

The top part of the view displays a rectangle with the selected contact infos (photo, name, address, etc). Under this rectangle, there is a UITableView displaying its actions (one cell, one action) :
[image]

When I scroll down to see the *"action 46"* for example, I would like to **progressively shrink the contact rectangle**, to finally completely hide it. (The actions are more important than the contact info, the user don't want to always see it on the screen, prefering to see the actions in full screen). 
For example, after a fast scroll, the result would be the following :

[image]

I have no idea about how to do that... Can you guide me a bit ?

**EDIT (precisions) :**

I want to display the tableView in fullscreen mode when scrolling down, because it represents no interest for the user to always see the contact infos on top of the screen. There is no behaviour when I click on a cell. The app just represents a contact (top part), and all its actions (bottom part, ie the tableView).
Anyway, my problem is that I can shrink the top part (contact infos) using this :

```
container.frame = CGRectMake(container.frame.origin.x,
                             container.frame.origin.y,
                             container.frame.size.width,
                             container.frame.size.height - 2);
```

But when I do the same replacing `-2`by `+2`, it doesn't work...

Comment: In xib rectangle clip subview check?

Comment: Adding the Contact Info as a Custom Cell (with a different section?) could be an idea. This way, you keep the same scrollview (UITableView).

Comment: It could be an idea, yep, but it's not optimized for my app because I need to display a searchBar just above the UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working solution ! Thanks Yohan and others for contribution.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.myTBV.contentOffset.y>100)
        self.myTBV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    else if(self.myTBV.contentOffset.y<100)
        self.myTBV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 211, 320, 357);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited my answer take a look. As per previous answer design the UI first. As per your wish first add search bar and one view for showing contacts details and a  table view which shows the list of actions.

Initially set UiView at bottom then down with table view. Add actions to the table view row
then use didscroll delegate method to identify whether scrolling started or not, When scrolling started decrease the size of the Contact view. Then when you scroll up do +2 the height of the Contact view and this is not full solution i gave just an idea you can implement how you want.

When you want tableview to cover full view after some scrolling check for contentoffset

```
     -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{


    NSLog(@"content offset:%f",self.tableGener.contentOffset.y);
    if(self.tableGener.contentOffset.y>100)
    {
    self.tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    self.contactview.frame = CGRectMake(self.contactview.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.contactview.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.contactview.frame.size.width,
                                 self.contactview.frame.size.height - 2);
    }

   else if(self.tableGener.contentOffset.y<100)
    {
        self.tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        self.contactview.frame = CGRectMake(self.contactview.frame.origin.x,
                                           self.contactview.frame.origin.y,
                                           self.contactview.frame.size.width,
                                           self.contactview.frame.size.height + 2);
    }

}
```

and this will repeat if scroll top to bottom , bottom to top. I think it will work if i did any mistake some one feel free to correct me.

Comment: Am not clear so you just want to make table view full size? but don want to add action for table cell is it so

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Yes, I just want to make tableView full size when scroll down, and shrink it to its original size when scroll up to its beginning. I tried your code, and it works just for the first part.
I explain : when I scroll down, the contact info view go out of the screen. Great. But when I scroll up to the beginning of the tableView, I want to see the contact info view again...
In your code, what is `tableGener` ? For me, it's a scrollView containing contact info and tableView.

Comment: tableGener is the tableview i didnt use scrollview and i said i just gave an idea @Erzékiel try like this place contactview in top after that place Tableview for me it is worked for both up scroll and down scroll

Comment: You're right, it works when I modify a line. Please see my answer. Thanks a lot for your help Yohan.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42927/discussion-between-yohan-and-erzekiel)

Answer (score 0):

in your .xib put ScrollView. and IBOutlet it "scrView".
put second view and IBOutlet it "tmpView" in that .xib and make desingning that view whatever you want and then put simple code it in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrView.delegate=self;
    [scrView addSubview:tmpView];
    scrView.contentSize = tmpView.frame.size;

}
```

I hope this works for you..

Answer (score 0):

```
    //-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)i


    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];

            if (_gender == textField)
            {

                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

                [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 320, 480)];

                [UIView commitAnimations];

            } // here,if _gender textfield is selected the frame will set according to setframe co=ordinates.
            else if (_webpage ==textField)

            {

                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

                [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -60, 320, 480)];

                [UIView commitAnimations];

            }

This is what I used to change the frame.This code shifts the view upwards when the stated textfield is selected, you need to pass the value of '**didselectrowatindex**' instead of textfield name..eg :- '_gender' etc.
```